# CS0103 Error: (Beginner-Intermediate) 'StorageClient' Does Not Exist in Current Context in .NET Project

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I am working on a .NET project and trying to integrate Google Cloud Storage using the Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 NuGet package. However, I am encountering an issue where the StorageClient class is not recognized, resulting in the CS0103 error: "The name 'StorageClient' does not exist in the current context."

I have already installed Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 package, and I am including it.
When using "Google.Cloud.Storage.V1" it doesn't recognize Google.
Here is the relevant part of the code:

ImageController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;

namespace backend.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ImagesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly string _bucketName = "your-bucket-name";

        [HttpPost("upload")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
                var storageClient = StorageClient.Create();
                var imageObjectName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
                var imageObjectPath = $"images/{imageObjectName}";

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    await storageClient.UploadObjectAsync(_bucketName, imageObjectPath, file.ContentType, memoryStream);
                }

                var imageUrl = $"https://storage.googleapis.com/myproduct-images/{imageObjectPath}";
                return Ok(new { Url = imageUrl });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

backend.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Storage.V1" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.cs

```
using backend.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<StorageClient>(provider =>
{
    return StorageClient.Create();
});

// Konfigurer DbContext
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

// Legg til CORS-tjenester
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
        builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
});

// Legg til andre tjenester
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Konfigurer HTTP request pipeline
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// Bruk CORS-policy
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I restarted Visual Studio code!